# Using Laravel's File Response with an S3 file

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am using Laravel 5.6.  The documentation says I can display a file in the user's browser with this code:

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

How can I get this to work with an S3 file which is not public?  I have tried the following:

```
return response()->file(Storage::disk('private')->path("my_directory/{$fileName}");
```

But it throws a 'file not found' error.

EDIT: Here's my work around:

```
return response(Storage::disk('private')->get("my_directory/{$fileName}"), 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        ->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline');
```

Comment: You saved my day. I was having CORS problem with S3 files, then I tried response()->file() solution which gave the same error "FileNotFoundException". I was desperate but your solution worked (for Laravel 8).